# bootstrap 4 columns are moving to next row when i see it on mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="frontendstyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            background:#eee;
            color:#666;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="header">
        <div class="main-menu">
            <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="row bg-primary p-4"> 
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 col-md-2  col-xs-5 bg-info">
                        <div class="brand-logo">
                            <img src="logo.png" class="rounded-circle">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-7 col-md-7  col-xs-3 bg-warning">
                        <div>smmm</div>
                    </div>

                    
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-xs-4 bg-secondary">
                        <div class="right-header">    
                            <div class="header-account">
                                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="header-cart">
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to force the 2 links to appear on 1 row for all screen sizes. Let me know if you succeed.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-xs-4 bg-secondary">
                    <div class="row right-header">    
                        <div class="col-6 header-account">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-6 header-cart">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```